# Why did the author write "at the point a of A" instead of "at a point a of A"?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, mathematics

I am reading a mathematics book ("Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres).

> Theorem 8.3 (The inverse function theorem).
>
> Let A be open in R^n; let f : A -> R^n be of class C^r. If Df(x) is non-singular
> at ***the*** point a of A, there is a neighborhood U of the point a such that f carries U
> in a one-to-one fashion onto an open set V of R^n and the inverse function is of class
> C^r.

Why did the author write "at ***the*** point a of A" instead of "at ***a*** point a of A"?
Why didn't the author write as follows?:

> Theorem 8.3' (The inverse function theorem).
>
> Let A be open in R^n; let f : A -> R^n be of class C^r. If Df(x) is non-singular
> at **a** point a of A, there is a neighborhood U of the point a such that f carries U
> in a one-to-one fashion onto an open set V of R^n and the inverse function is of class
> C^r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is using the variable *a* to specify a specific point, hence the use of the word "the point *a*".  It is true that this point is not specified, so you might think of it as being anywhere, but the intent is to speak of a specific, albeit not-nailed-down point.  But he could have written "a point *a*" without its being erroneous.

Comment: Charles B. Cameron, Thank you very much for your answer!